# Gravity Forms PDF Graphs & Charts JPgraph

Tags: wordpress, pdf, pdf-generation, gravity-forms-plugin, jpgraph

I am trying to figure out how to add graphs and charts to the gravity form pdf that I create. I can easily create tables using the data array, but cannot figure out how to add this data to a pie chart or bar graph.

Other have mentioned using jpgraph to accomplish this, but I do not know where to add this jpgraph file to site.

Any help on this topic would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://gfchart.com/ check this link.

Answer (score -1):

Or this free one could help you: https://wordpress.org/plugins/gf-charts-reports/
It works well for creating chart on your page online (using chartsjs), but i don't known if you can integrate them directly into you PDF using Gravity PDF.
Let us known!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13936722)

Comment: Yes sorry, completing my answer now